# PHP - Mostrar url passada na na pagina

Tags: php, url

Estou precisando visualizar a linha URL que foi passada na chamada da página PHP

Preciso de ver os parâmetros pois não estão vindo corretamente

Obrigado

Comment: Vê se te ajuda: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 2):

A variável em questão é a `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Poderíamos pegar a **URL** chamada da seguinte forma precisamente:

```
$urlAtual = "https://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Dentro da variável `$urlAtual` teria exatamente a URL completa. Ali deixamos fixo o `https`, mas isso também é possível de ser verificado usando o seguinte:

```
$urlAtual = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'http' : 'https') . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

> ⚠️ Esse código não é totalmente seguro, pois o cliente e o servidor podem definir `HTTP_HOST` e `REQUEST_URI` com valores arbitrários. É absolutamente necessário sanitizar(higienizar) ambos os valores e fazer a validação de entrada adequada ([CWE-20](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/20.html)). Essas variáveis não devem ser usadas ​​em nenhum contexto de segurança.

E no caso de querer pegar especificamente os valores passados como parâmetro na URL, via método GET, a variável em questão seria: `$_GET["NOME_PARAMETRO"]`, onde NOME_PARAMETRO é o nome do parâmetro passado na URL. Exemplo: http://localhost/minhaurl/index.php?teste=1, onde a variável `$_GET["teste"]` terá o valor "1" contido nela.

Comment: Ok Pedro valeu!!! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!!